# How to Mapping CDN Endpoint to Azure Cloud Service Single Box ( Multiple Sites (Reset API) in One Service)

Tags: azure-cloud-services, azure-cdn

We have single cloud service for all rest api services including HTML app.

I need to map our CDN endpoint to HTML App.

Please suggest solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've provided, you should just be able to create a CDN endpoint, and set the "Origin Path" to the relative path of your HTML App, during creation in the Azure Portal.

Hope that helps.